# How to restart OpenStack services after restart/logout?

Tags: 12.04, cloud, openstack

I have successfully configured OpenStack following [this](http://ilearnstack.com/2013/04/26/setting-up-a-single-node-openstack-environment/) tutorial.

The problem is that when I logout of my system or restart, and then try to access the OpenStack dashboard, it says `page not found`. It seems that OpenStack is not started.

I want to know what are the commands to run OpenStack's services?

Comment: Sorry the link is blocked in my place. Is it a devstack installation?

Comment: @Jobin I have sorted out. Thanks.

Now I need to know how to install Apache Hadoop on OpenStack. Any idea? I installed it cloning this
git clone https://github.com/ilearnstack/cloudgear.git

Comment: Would be great if you post the solution as answer here and post a new question as a new question.

Comment: @UmairAyub can you please share how you sorted out this problem?

Answer (score 2):

First, search for "rejoin-stack.sh" on your machine, copy and save its path on your machine.

Second, use the terminal by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard.

Compute Nodes:

Third type:

```
sudo service openstack-nova-api restart
sudo service openstack-nova-cert restart
sudo service openstack-nova-consoleauth restart
sudo service openstack-nova-scheduler restart
sudo service openstack-nova-conductor restart
sudo service openstack-nova-novncproxy restart
```

Network Nodes:

Fourth type:

```
sudo service neutron-server restart
sudo service neutron-dhcp-agent restart
sudo service neutron-l3-agent restart
sudo service neutron-metadata-agent restart
```

[[Open Virtual Switch if installed]]

```
sudo service neutron-openvswitch-agent restart
```

Cinder Nodes:

Fifth type:

```
sudo service openstack-cinder-api restart
sudo service openstack-cinder-backup restart
sudo service openstack-cinder-scheduler restart
sudo service openstack-cinder-volume restart
```

If you want to get all the names of the services installed:

Sixth Type:

```
sudo service --status-all | grep nova
sudo service --status-all | grep neutron
sudo service --status-all | grep cinder
```

One last thing to do is to type:

```
cd /path/to/rejoin-stack.sh/folder
sudo ./rejoin-stack.sh
```

then wait for the confirmation to start using OpenStack again.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution I found is by openstack-utils

```
yum install -y openstack-utils dnsmasq-utils
openstack-service restart
```

now verify the services

```
openstack-status -l
```

Tested on queens and rocky.